# Facebook Stack changed redirect method on final callback

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, callback

We have been using some very limited browsers on dumb feature phones and up until 2 weeks ago it was working perfectly. At that point the last redirect no longer issues a 302 redirect but uses javascript to redirect. Unfortunately these devices do not support javascript.

Has any one found a way around this? or a method to change this.

Thank You.